# Fetch API and CDN links. Risks?

Tags: javascript, fetch, cdn

I had an idea "Why don't we use the fetch API the same way we use a script tag ?" and then I gave it a try.

```
(() => fetch (`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/diff_match_patch/20121119/diff_match_patch.js`)
.then (data => data.text ().then (data => eval (data)))) ();
```

Sor far, it works, but why didn't I've seen it before ?

Comment: [`eval` is a security risk](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/94017/what-are-the-security-issues-with-eval-in-javascript). Your code is open to code injection attacks

Comment: On top of what Liam said, it's slower and debugging (if possible anyway) will be harder.

Comment: on top of that if this doesn't block and your cdn is slow your page will render before the script is loaded potentially breaking

Comment: I think we can sum it up here before we make a list of the comments section. You should avoid `eval` at all costs.

Comment: Thanks everyone, it would be really great if someone could make such a list. I've read the Information Security link but unfortunately, being not that efficient in english and security understanding, I'm not sure to fully get the point (Besides it being a no-no).
Thanks again !